# Jarsigner can't sign .apk but displays no errors

Tags: android, cordova, terminal, apk, jarsigner

I'm trying to update an old app that I, sincerely, don't remember if it was signed using command line or Android Studio or whatever.

Now I have an unsigned apk named "android-release-unsigned.apk" but when I run the command: `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore /Users/MyUser/Desktop/nameofmyapp.jks platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk "my_alias"` and enter my password it begins the process of generate the unialigned apk, even appears a file named android-release-unsigned.apk.sig, then this file disappears and nothing more happens.

The terminal show no errors and ends with `jar signed.` so I'm absolutely lost.

Im working on a Mac, but I tried on Windows and the result is the same.

I don't know if it matters but I renamed my .jks file to myapp.jks, also, the code of the app is completely new because I started it like a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is **SO** embarrassing.

For some reason, I was expecting that the `jarsigner` command generates a file named android-release-**unaligned**.apk, and then apply the zipalign command to it.

Probably nobody will never do this dumb mistake, but just in case: **just align that `*-release-unsigned.apk`!**

Comment: how do you solved?

Comment: Well that was long ago, but my problem was that I was trying to sign the incorrect file.
I was trying to sign `android-release-unaligned.apk` instead of `android-release-unsigned.apk` which is the correct

Comment: i finally solved by added `sudo`, kind of different problem but thanks